# codeigniter file_get_content or curl is not working in our dev server

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, curl, file-get-contents

Needs to get location details for the latitude and longitude,
It just work in other server - functioning correctly, but trying with client dev server getting error, i have tried with this about 4 hours - till didn't get the result. assist would be helpful.
Here is my code:

```
public function index() {
    echo $this->getLocation('39.2323', '-97.3828');
}

function getLocation($lat, $long) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" . trim($lat) . "," . trim($long) . "&sensor=false";
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    $address = '';
    if ($status == "OK") {
        $address = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
    }
    return $address;
}
```

Am getting the error like below:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message:
>   file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.2323,-97.3828&sensor=false)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed
>   out
>
> Filename: webservice/Test.php Line Number: 17
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/colanful/public_html/hoa/application/controllers/webservice/Test.php
>   Line: 17 Function: file_get_contents
>
> File:
>   /home/colanful/public_html/hoa/application/controllers/webservice/Test.php
>   Line: 12 Function: getaddress
>
> File: /home/colanful/public_html/hoa/index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change an ini setting on the clients dev server.

From @Aillyn's answer:

The setting you are looking for is allow_url_fopen.

You have two ways of getting around it without changing php.ini, one of them is to use fsockopen(), and the other is to use cURL.

I recommend using cURL over file_get_contents() anyways, since it was built for this.

Comment: I have tried with curl too, not getting the result.

Comment: @Wahidh: have you found the solution ?if so post it.